# A class of unipotent group actions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-actions

Consider algebraic actions of unipotent groups $G$ on affine spaces $X=\mathbb{C}^n$. I am looking for a condition that would guarantee that the quotient $X/G$ exists and is also an affine space. For instance:

Suppose $X$ is itself isomorphic to a unipotent group and $G$ acts via compositions of left translations with group automorphisms. Suppose the action is such that every point of $X$ has trivial stabilizer. Is it true that $X/G$ is isomorphic to affine space?

UPDATE: It turns out, by replacing $X/G$ with $G\backslash X\rtimes A/A$ where $A$ is the image of $G$ in the group of automorphisms of $X$, the question is reduced to the corresponding question for double cosets, which is again a special case of the original question. So here is an equivalent question:

Suppose a unipotent group $G$ contains unipotent subgroups $G_1, G_2$ such that $G_1\cap x G_2 x^{-1} = \{e\}$ for all $x\in G$.  Is the double coset space $G_1 \backslash G / G_2$ isomorphic to affine space?

Comment: "The action doesn't have fixed points" has two possible meanings: no global fixed point, vs free action. What do you mean?

Comment: @YCor Sorry, I rephrased the question. I meant free action. I would also like to understand the non-free case, but I don't know what kind of property to expect.

Comment: If it is indeed isomorphic, then I think I know a formula for an isomorphism. You may assume that your unipotent groups $G$ is embedded in ${\rm GL}(V)$. Then its Lie algebra $\frak g$ is embedded in ${\frak gl}(V)$, and the exponential map $\exp\colon {\frak g}\to G$ is a (polynomial) isomorphism of varieties.

Comment: Let $U\subset V$ be a complement in $\frak g$ to ${\frak g}_1\oplus{\frak g}_2$. In other words, ${\frak g}= {\frak g}_1\oplus U\oplus{\frak g}_2$. I  expect that for a suitable choice of $U$ (or even for any choice of $U$), the map $$e\colon \,{\frak g}= {\frak g}_1\oplus U\oplus{\frak g}_2\,\to\, G,\quad g_1+u+g_2\,\mapsto\, \exp(g_1)\cdot\exp(u)\cdot\exp(g_2)$$  will be an isomorphism of varieties. This will answer your question.

Comment: @Mikhail Borovoi, it would be great if it works. Note that for arbitrary $U$ it doesn't work even for trivial $\mathfrak g_2$ and one-dimensional $\mathfrak g_1$. Unless $\mathfrak g_1$ is in the center.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no". In this paper: Winkelmann, J. On free holomorphic ℂ-actions on ℂn and homogeneous stein manifolds. Math. Ann. 286, 593–612 (1990) a free *affine linear action* of $G_a\times G_a$ on $\mathbb{C}^6$ is given in such a way that the quotient is not an affine variety. So for $X=G_a^6$, $G=G_a^2$, we obtain a counter-example.

By the way, in op. cit. this action is reduced to a triangular algebraic action of $G_a$ on $\mathbb{C}^5$. There is also an example there of a free triangular algebraic action of $G_a$ on $\mathbb{C}^4$ with non-Hausdorff quotient. It is not hard to check that the class of triangular algebraic actions coincides with the class of actions of $G_1$ on $G/G_2$ where $G_1, G_2$ range over unipotent subgroups of unipotent groups $G$.